# String method in Java: charAt()

Tags: java

I have an assignment that I'm finding a bit difficult. We're reading an external file to get the numbers needed for the program, which is not a problem. Here is the prompt:

To check the validity of the code you need to analyze each digit in the code including the check digit. Assume that the first digit is in position zero, add the digits in the even positions and multiply the result by 3.  Add this to the sum of the odd positioned digits.  Only if the total is a multiple of 10 is the UPC number valid. Write a program that reads a UPC code (as a string) from an external file, analyze the code, and output the code and a label “Invalid” or “Valid”.

Sample Output: UPC Code:

016499215511    Valid

372415613274  Invalid

155512994610    Valid

011165459192  Invalid

838241762110  Invalid

Here is what I have in my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Prog700d
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Guest\\Documents\\java programs\\Prog700d\\Prog700d.in"));
        while(kbReader.hasNextLine())
        {
            String upc = kbReader.nextLine();
            int length = upc.length();
            int a = upc.charAt(0);
            System.out.println(a);
```

My main issue is with the charAt(). I think that if I use charAt(), then I will get the character at the given index. So I decided to test this by using charAt(0), and I ended up getting these numbers:

49
55
53
49
51

I am really confused on how I got these numbers, and honestly have no idea what went wrong. I can do the rest of the program (such as the formula, printing out everything, etc.), but I don't know how to fix the charAt() problem. I know I can handle the rest of the assignment, but I have no idea what went wrong with this. If someone could provide some guidance on how to fix issue, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The value of a character is a code.  The character "5" has a numerical value of decimal 53 (hex 35).  Google "ASCII table".  You can use the method `Character.digit(myChar, 10)` to return the numeric value of the digit.  (Use `isDigit` to test if the character is a digit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These numbers are UNICODE code points of the digits. If you need to get the digit value, subtract `'0'` from them:

```
int a = upc.charAt(0) - '0';
System.out.println(a);
```

The reason this expression gives you the digit's value is that UNICODE code points of decimal digits have consecutive integer values: `'0'` is 48, `'1'` is 49, `'2'` is 50, and so on. Subtracting `'0'` from the code point yields the value of the digit.

**EDIT :** As of Java 1.5 you can use [`Character.digit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28int,%20int%29) to get the numeric value of the corresponding digit:

```
int a = Character.digit(upc.charAt(0), 10);
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: It's more "official" to use `Character.digit()`.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks! I missed that part of the update back in my Java days. It's nice to know that Java has added something to deal with this, and was kind enough to throw in the radix parameter, too!

Comment: The Character class has been there pretty much forever.  Not sure if all of the digit/getNumericValue methods were there, but some were.  (Just checked -- `digit(char,int)` has been there forever; `digit(int,int)` is newer.)

Comment: @HotLicks Acording to the docs, `digit` has been added in Java 5.

Comment: Bah. These numbers are not even unicode code points. They were ascii first, only unicode by inclusion way after the fact. And doing charAt(0) - '0' relies on the historical accident of the ordering in ascii. Works but smelly. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

charAt returns a value of char type.

change your code to:

```
String upc = kbReader.nextLine();
int length = upc.length();
char a = upc.charAt(0);
int b = Character.getNumericValue(a);  
System.out.println(b);
```

Should be ok like that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit verbose but....

```
% cat check.java
public class check {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        String s = arg[0];
        if (s.matches("[0-9]{12}")) {
            int evens = Character.digit(s.charAt(0),10) +
                        Character.digit(s.charAt(2),10) + 
                        Character.digit(s.charAt(4),10) + 
                        Character.digit(s.charAt(6),10) + 
                        Character.digit(s.charAt(8),10) + 
                        Character.digit(s.charAt(10),10);
            int odds = Character.digit(s.charAt(1),10) + 
                       Character.digit(s.charAt(3),10) + 
                       Character.digit(s.charAt(5),10) + 
                       Character.digit(s.charAt(7),10) + 
                       Character.digit(s.charAt(9),10) + 
                        Character.digit(s.charAt(11),10);
            int sum = evens * 3 + odds;
            if ((sum % 10) == 0) { System.out.println("YES"); return; }
        }
        System.out.println("NO"); 
    }
}
% javac check.java
% java -classpath . check 016499215511
YES
% java -classpath . check 372415613274
NO
% java -classpath . check 37241561327
NO
% java -classpath . check 01649921551
NO
%
```